# ¿jquery DataTables.js puede mostrar una tabla de forma vertical?

Tags: datatables

Estoy trabajando con jquery DataTable pero debo mostrar mi tabla de forma vertical, es decir, las columnas como filas, por ejemplo:

[image: Headers verticales]

Comment: Podrias mostrarnos el código de cómo lo has hecho? o que es lo que llevas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es posible, si bien DataTables tiene una [opción](https://legacy.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html) para modificara el dom, esto esta limitado a que la table se pinte en su totalidad

> ```
> l - Length changing
> f - Filtering input
> t - The table!
> i - Information
> p - Pagination
> r - pRocessing
> < and > - div elements
> <"class" and > - div with a class
> ```

Si quiza jugando con el metodo `render` podriamos ajustarnos un poco, no valdria la pena el esfuerzo, sera mejor hacer una implementación propia

Comment: Ya lo sospechaba, solo era para no dejar nada suelto. Muchas gracias. jasilva.